# select specific time from previous day

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I basically want to select data between 7pm the previous day and NOW().  I'm not sure the best practice or most efficient way to do this on an automated report generated by a query I could write.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp BETWEEN curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND 
  NOW()
```

How do I get the curdate() - interval 1 day to start at 7pm of the previous day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curdate() returns just the date, e.g. 2018-03-21. Time in this case is omitted, but would be 00:00:00. To start at 07:00 pm just add another 19 hours like this:

```
select curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 19 HOUR;
```

Comment: That actually was a lot simpler than I had anticipated.  I was over-thinking it.